# Need fixed position div to stop part way down the page

Tags: html, css

I've created a div and placed an image on it.  Currently the image goes all the way to the bottom of the page, disappearing behind the other image in a seperate div and completely hiding the footer div.  I need the image to be fixed and scroll down the page but when it reaches the div with the footer I need it to stop (behind the other image).  Here's the relevant code:

CSS

```
.grass {
    height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #80BD01;
}

.padtb30 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    /*vertical-align: bottom;*/
    text-align: center;
}

.buildings {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.citydiv {
    /*position: fixed;*/
    height: 245px;
    width: 100%;
    background-image:url("../assets/images/sunwave-backcity.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

}

footer {
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```

HTML

```
    <div class="citydiv"></div>
    <div class="padt120">
        <img src="~/assets/images/sunwave-about-buildings.png" alt="Sunwave Buildings" class="buildings"/>
        <!--<div class="green navbar"></div><-->
        <div class="grass"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<footer class="padtb30">
    <div class="container center">
        <span class="copyright"><small class="lightgrey-text">&copy; Copyright 2016.  All Rights Reserved.  ONEnergy Inc. <a href="http://limeadvertisinginc.com/sunwave-test/public/privacypolicy">Privacy Policy</a>
        </small></span>
    </div>
</footer>
```

And I'll attach a couple of images.  One is what it should look like and the other is what it currently looks like.
[What I got:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTMmO.jpg)
[What I want:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQiH4.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to achieve this by placing the footer of the page, which I wanted to remain at the bottom of the page and not have content flow behind it, inside of another div called "bottom".  Then I set "bottom" position to relative.  Here's the code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="bottom">
    <div class="padt120">
        <img src="~/Images/sunwave-about-buildings.png" alt="Sunwave Buildings" class="buildings" />
        <div class="grass"></div>
    </div>

    <footer class="padtb30">
        <span class="copyright">
            <small class="lightgrey-text">
                &copy; Copyright 2016.  All Rights Reserved.  ONEnergy Inc. <a href="http://limeadvertisinginc.com/sunwave-test/public/privacypolicy">Privacy Policy</a>
            </small>
        </span>
    </footer>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.bottom {
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use layer properties of CSS3 with z-index to make your image's div position higher on your page.

Comment: I tried setting the position to absolute for padtb30 and the z-index to several values but the element did not move.

Answer (score 0):

Set `padtb30` to `display:relative` and then set the `z-index` to like 100 to tell it stack above all the other content.

More information here:
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/

Comment: When I try to enter display:relative under padtb30 in the css Visual Studio says "relative is not a valid value for the display property" and adding "z-index: xx" where xx is a value did not change the positioning of the element no matter what value I entered.

Comment: Not sure why it would be saying it's not a valid value, use it all the time myself. Granted, not in VS: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp 

Z-index will only work in relative or absolute positioning.